# Color of Radiobutton in Tcl/Tk 8.5

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

is it possible to modify the color of a radiobutton's dot (i.e. only the fill-color of the diamond/circle)?
I am already using the classic theme, in order to get the old diamonds. But unfortunately, the fill-color of those diamonds is always some red and I need bright green.

Is that possible? Maybe by creating an own widget that "inherits/extends" the basic radio button?

Any kind of advice is welcome.

Kind regards,
mefiX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `radiobutton` command has `-selectcolor` option. Just specify the color for this option.

```
set a 1
radiobutton .b1 -selectcolor green -variable a -value 1 -text "Option 1"
radiobutton .b2 -selectcolor green -variable a -value 2 -text "Option 2"
radiobutton .b3 -selectcolor green -variable a -value 3 -text "Option 3"
pack .b1 .b2 .b3
```

If you do not want to specify the color for each radiobutton individually, you can set this colot in xresources database.

```
option add *Radiobutton.selectColor green
set a 1
radiobutton .b1 -variable a -value 1 -text "Option 1"
radiobutton .b2 -variable a -value 2 -text "Option 2"
radiobutton .b3 -variable a -value 3 -text "Option 3"
pack .b1 .b2 .b3
```

---

**EDIT**: Solution for ttk:

```
ttk::style theme use classic
ttk::style map TRadiobutton -indicatorcolor {pressed #d9d9d9 selected green}
set a 1
ttk::radiobutton .b1 -variable a -value 1 -text "Option 1"
ttk::radiobutton .b2 -variable a -value 2 -text "Option 2"
ttk::radiobutton .b3 -variable a -value 3 -text "Option 3"
pack .b1 .b2 .b3
```

You can define your own ttk::style for radiobutton and use it for particular widgets if you do not want to redefine the global style:

```
ttk::style layout TRadiobuttonGreen [ttk::style layout TRadiobutton]
ttk::style configure TRadiobuttonGreen {*}[ttk::style configure TRadiobutton]
ttk::style map TRadiobuttonGreen {*}[ttk::style map TRadiobutton] -indicatorcolor {pressed #d9d9d9 selected green}

ttk::radiobutton .b1 -style TRadiobuttonGreen -variable a -value 1 -text "Option 1"
...
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Note that this doesn't work on all platforms. [JobsianMindTrick] But then you don't want to change the colors of menubuttons on MacOS X. [/JobsianMindTrick]

Comment: Unforunately, this doesn't work for me in TCL 8.5. Furthermore, did you use Tk or Ttk?

Comment: @mefiX I've added solution for ttk.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. Actually, I like the style-map mechanism!