# TCL: How to change colour of radiobutton upon checking certain condition

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I wanted to change color of a radiobutton after checking if some files are present in a directory, but could not able to achieve it, as not sure configure `-background color` works for radio button.

Here is a sample code looks like

```tcl
set topdir $path

ttk::checkbutton .top.d.z.$t -text $v -variable s -command [list select_lib $v $elem $g $t] $t] \
        -value $v.kill -padx 2 -pady 2 
if {file exist $path/rc.log == 1} {
    #change color to green in  widget
} else {
    # retain same background of radio button
}
```

Please suggest any method to achieve this.

Comment: Also, the test should be `{[file exists $path/rc.log]}`, but I presume this is just demonstration code.

Comment: I guess another question is, do you want to change the color of the radiobutton, or do you want to change whether it is selected?

Answer (score 1):

OK, with thanks to RLE and Brad Lanam for their descriptions of ttk style on the wiki.

Create and locate a radiobutton:

```
pack [ttk::radiobutton .b -text foo]
```

Create a custom style based on the default `TRadiobutton` style, with the background set to green:

```
ttk::style configure greenstyle.TRadiobutton -background green
```

Apply this style to the radiobutton to turn the background green:

```
.b configure -style greenstyle.TRadiobutton
```

Revert to the normal background color:

```
.b configure -style TRadiobutton
```

When changing colors, etc on a themed widget, one can decide to change

- The default style (in this case `TRadiobutton`): this affects all widgets of the same type
- A substyle, as in this example (`greenstyle.TRadiobutton`)
- A cloned style (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743302/color-of-radiobutton-in-tcl-tk-8-5?rq=1) for an example)
- A scratch-built style (following the examples in the `C:\Tcl\lib\tk8.6\ttk` directory on Windows): experts only.

**Edit by Brad Lanam:**

**More Information on ttk::radiobutton colors**

Some Definitions:

- Background: The overall background color behind everything
- Foreground: The color of the text on the radiobutton label
- Indicator Color: The color of the indicator.

These options can be set using the `ttk::style` command:

```
ttk::style configure greenstyle.TRadiobutton -indicatorcolor lightgreen
ttk::style map greenstyle.TRadiobutton -indicatorcolor \
    [list selected darkgreen pressed white]
```

Apply the set and reset as above.

Documentation:
[pack](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm),
[ttk::radiobutton (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_radiobutton.htm),
[Introduction to the Tk theme engine](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_intro.htm),
[Changing Widget Colors (ttk::radiobutton)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/37973#pagetoc757a68e7)

Comment: I am sorry , actually using ttk:radiobutton and its not working for it.
ttk::checkbutton .top.d.z.$t -text $v -variable s -command [list select_lib $v $elem $g $t]

Comment: @DanishSheikh: all right. The themed widgets are harder to configure that way, and personally I never do. I'll look into it later today, unless hopefully Brad Lanam checks in and gives you the answer right away.

Comment: Yes, I did some research into the various options to change colors.  (I can't get the darn thing to display as code).  Edit is pending.   What operating system are you using?

Comment: These options are the same for `ttk::checkbutton`.

Comment: I am using RHEL5 and TK version 8.6